# Re-Populate column in a relational data frame after randomization in R

Tags: r, relational-database, filtering, conditional-formatting

I have a data frame of individuals and their spouses with some personal information (i.e. last names) that I have randomized with plyr::mapvalues in order to protect identities.  Here is a reproducible example of how it looked before and after changing the surnames:

```
# before
d <- data.frame(id = c(1:6), 
                first_name = c('Jeff', 'Marilyn', 'Gwyn', 
                               'Alice', 'Sam', 'Sarah'), 
                surname = c('Goldbloom', 'Monroe', 'Paltrow', 'Goldbloom',
                            'Smith', 'Silverman'), 
                spouse_id = c(2, 1, 1, 5, 4, "NA"), 
                spouse = c('Marilyn Monroe', 'Jeff Goldbloom', 'Jeff Goldbloom', 
                           'Sam Smith', 'Alice Goldbloom', 'NA'))
d
> id first_name   surname spouse_id          spouse
   1       Jeff Goldbloom         2  Marilyn Monroe
   2    Marilyn    Monroe         1  Jeff Goldbloom
   3       Gwyn   Paltrow         1  Jeff Goldbloom
   4      Alice Goldbloom         5       Sam Smith
   5        Sam     Smith         4 Alice Goldbloom
   6      Sarah Silverman        NA              NA

# replacement names to serve as surnames (doesn't matter what they are, just
 that the ratios remain the same as before; mapvalues takes care of this)

repnames <- c("Arman"   , "Clovis"  , "Garner"  , "Casey"  ,  "Birch")
s <- unique(d$surname)
d$surname <- plyr::mapvalues(d$surname, from = s, to = repnames) #replace surnames

# After replacement, the dataframe looks like:
d
>   id first_name surname spouse_id          spouse
    1       Jeff   Arman         2  Marilyn Monroe
    2    Marilyn  Clovis         1  Jeff Goldbloom
    3       Gwyn  Garner         1  Jeff Goldbloom
    4      Alice   Arman         5       Sam Smith
    5        Sam   Casey         4 Alice Goldbloom
    6      Sarah   Birch        NA              NA
```

Each person has his or her own `id` number, but not all people have spouses.  If a person does have a spouse, their spouse's individual `id` is reflected in the `spouse_id` column.  I did this so that I could filter individuals and their spouses separately later using something like `dplyr::filter(d, spouse %in% spouse_id)`.

My question is, how can I use the relational `id` and `spouse_id` columns to re-populate the `spouse` column so that it reflects the new, randomized surnames? i.e. the final expected output would be:

```
  id first_name surname spouse_id         spouse
  1       Jeff   Arman         2     Marilyn Clovis
  2    Marilyn  Clovis         1     Jeff Arman
  3       Gwyn  Garner         1     Jeff Arman
  4      Alice   Arman         5     Sam Casey
  5        Sam   Casey         4     Alice Arman
  6      Sarah   Birch        NA             NA
```

> 

...So some concatenation will be involved on the `first_name` and `surname` columns.  I've never done something quite so conditional in R - in Excel I guess it would be nested VLOOKUP functions...

Thanks, sorry it's so specific but hopefully it presents a fun challenge to someone out there.

Comment: Can you show the expected output?

Comment: @akrun sorry, edited correctly now!

Comment: Also are your NA strings or actual NAs? In your example are strings

Comment: They are actual NAs - df is huge, just wanted to make a small example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your NAs are actual NAs, then

```
d$spouse <- paste(d$first_name, d$surname)[d$spouse_id]
d$spouse
#[1] "Marilyn Clovis" "Jeff Arman"     "Jeff Arman"     "Sam Casey"      "Alice Arman"    NA
```